# Apache Apollo Connection Refused

Tags: apache, connection, messaging, stomp, apollo

I have installed Apache Apollo and running it successfully. I can access its web dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:61680/.

I want to connect to this via STOMP. I'm using the library [StompKit][1] to do this.

```
private let host: String = "127.0.0.1"
private let port: UInt = 61680

private var client: STOMPClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    client = STOMPClient(host: host, port: port)
    connect()
}
```

Connecting fails with the error **Connection refused**.

This is the *apollo.xml* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version
  2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by
  applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under
  the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES
  OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
  For more information on how configure this file please
  reference:

  http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/versions/1.7.1/website/documentation/user-manual.html
  -->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/activemq/apollo">

  <notes>
    The default configuration with tls/ssl enabled.
  </notes>

  <log_category console="console" security="security" connection="connection" audit="audit"/>


  <authentication domain="apollo"/>
  <!-- Give admins full access -->
  <access_rule allow="admins" action="*"/>
  <access_rule allow="*" action="connect" kind="connector"/>


  <virtual_host id="mybroker">
    <!--
      You should add all the host names that this virtual host is known as
      to properly support the STOMP 1.1 virtual host feature.
      -->
    <host_name>mybroker</host_name>
    <host_name>localhost</host_name>
    <host_name>127.0.0.1</host_name>

    <!-- Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host -->
    <!-- <authentication enabled="false"/> -->

    <!-- Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host -->
    <!-- <authentication enabled="false"/> -->
    <access_rule allow="users" action="connect create destroy send receive consume"/>


    <!-- You can delete this element if you want to disable persistence for this virtual host -->
    <leveldb_store directory="${apollo.base}/data"/>


  </virtual_host>

  <web_admin bind="http://127.0.0.1:61680"/>
  <web_admin bind="https://127.0.0.1:61681"/>

  <connector id="tcp" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61613" connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="tls" bind="tls://0.0.0.0:61614" connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="ws"  bind="ws://0.0.0.0:61623"  connection_limit="2000"/>
  <connector id="wss" bind="wss://0.0.0.0:61624" connection_limit="2000"/>

  <key_storage file="${apollo.base}/etc/keystore" password="password" key_password="password"/>

</broker>
```

**Attempt 1**

Only answer I could find related to this is [this][2] (Although it's for MQTT). Anyway, I modified the apollo.xml file by adding the `authentication` line.

```
<virtual_host id="mybroker">
    <authentication enabled="false"/>
...
```

But that changed nothing.

**Attempt 2:**

The web dashboard has a username/password login. So I tried a different method of StompKit.

```
client.connectWithLogin("admin", passcode: "password") { connectedFrame, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error during connecting: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Connected!")
    }
}
```

Still the error persists.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, STOMP clients can connect to Apollo on port **61613**. Port 61680 is for the web admin interface.

Your configuration contains

```
<connector id="tcp" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61613" connection_limit="2000"/>
```

so I assume that

```
private let port: UInt = 61613
```

in your code should solve the problem

---

Note: you can use netstat or TCPView to verify that the port 61613 is open

Comment: I chaned the port number to `61613` but still got the same error. Then I changed the host to `0.0.0.0` and tried again but still no luck.